# Foreign Key references primary key in the same table grails domain class

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I have a table called person with primary key as id and in the same table I have a foreign key as master_id that references id (primry key) in the same table person. How do I create my domain class in grails for person. ?

Table Person

```
 Integer person_id PK auto_increment
 String name
 String address
 String city
 Integer  FK master_id references Person(person_id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a field of the appropriate type with a name of `master`:

```
class Person {
     Person master
}
```

Comment: Thankyou! Does it require any mapping or foreign key association in domain class?

Comment: No, as long as you follow the conventions, it just works.  Here, the field name has to be same as the id column, minus `_id`.